# try edit record in symfony (file VichUploaderBundle)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4, vichuploaderbundle

I try edit record in Symfony .i can edit text record but I cannot edit a new file on record.((file saved in Storage but don't save on database))

How i can do that in Symfony 3.4 with VichUploaderBundle 1.4 ...
for insert, I have not any problem I upload the image to storage and save in database
.....

it is my editAction

```
/**
 * @Route("/Article/editArticle/{id}",name="editArticle")
 */
public function editArticleAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $articleRepo=$em->getRepository('AdminBundle:Article');
    $articleata = $articleRepo->find($id);
    // $satelliteImage=new satelliteImage;
    $article = new Article();
    $form = $this->createForm(ArticleType::class,$article,array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('editArticle',array('id' => $articleata->getId())),
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'dropzone',
            'id'  => "my-awesome-dropzone"
        ),
        'method' => 'POST',
        [
            'name'        => $articleata->getName(),
            'title'       => $articleata->getTitle(),
            'subject'     => $articleata->getSubject(),
            'description' => $articleata->getDescription(),
            'smallPic'    => $articleata->getSmallPic(),
            'largPic'     => $articleata->getLargPic(),
            'displayStatus' => $articleata->getDisplayStatus()]
    ));
   //

    if ($request->getMethod() == Request::METHOD_POST){
 $form->handleRequest($request);
        $article->setName($form->get('name')->getData());
        $article->setTitle($form->get('title')->getData());
        $article->setSubject($form->get('subject')->getData());
        $article->setDescription($form->get('description')->getData());
        $article->setDisplayStatus($form->get('displayStatus')->getData());
        $article->setSmallPic($form->get('imageFile')->getData());
        $article->setLargPic($form->get('imageFile2')->getData());
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $em->flush();
    }
    return $this->render('AdminBundle:Article:edit_article.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'Articles' => $articleata


    ));
}
```

my Entity

```
private $smallPic;

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="articles_images", fileNameProperty="smallPic")
     * @var File
     */
    private $imageFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $updatedAt;
   /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="largPic", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $largPic;
    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="articles_images", fileNameProperty="largPic")
     * @var File
     */
    private $imageFile2;

 public function setImageFile(File $smallPic = null)
    {
        $this->imageFile = $smallPic;

        // VERY IMPORTANT:
        // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using Doctrine,
        // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
        if ($smallPic) {
            // if 'updatedAt' is not defined in your entity, use another property
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now');
        }
    }

    public function getImageFile()
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }

    public function setSmallPic($smallPic)
    {
        $this->smallPic = $smallPic;
    }

    public function getSmallPic()
    {
        return $this->smallPic;
    }
    public function setImageFile2(File $largPic = null)
    {
        $this->imageFile2 = $largPic;

        // VERY IMPORTANT:
        // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using Doctrine,
        // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
        if ($largPic) {
            // if 'updatedAt' is not defined in your entity, use another property
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now');
        }
    }

    public function getImageFile2()
    {
        return $this->imageFile2;
    }


    /**
     * Set largPic
     *
     * @param string $largPic
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setLargPic($largPic)
    {
        $this->largPic = $largPic;
    }

    /**
     * Get largPic
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLargPic()
    {
        return $this->largPic;
    }
.
.
.
```

FromType

```
 ->add('imageFile', VichFileType::class, array(
                'label' => "smallpic",
                'required' => false,
                'allow_delete' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
                'download_link' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
            ))
            ->add('imageFile2', VichFileType::class, array(
                'label' => "largPic",
                'required' => false,
                'allow_delete' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
                'download_link' => true, // not mandatory, default is true

            ))
```

config.yml

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm

    mappings:
        articles_images:
            uri_prefix: '%app.path.articles_images%'
            upload_destination: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/images/articles'
            inject_on_load:     true
            delete_on_update:   true
            delete_on_remove:   true
```

Answer (score 1):

Before the flush you need to:

`$em->persist($article);`

UPDATED:

In general, VichUploader Bundle is not considered best practice to upload images anymore. Storing image data in the DB really bloats up it's size, and it's not recommended. You have another entity called media, with some fields like `hash`, `path`, `size`, etc... and you should use the filesystem, with an abstraction if you want to change to, for example, Amazon S3 or Google Storage in the future.

Take a look at the aswesome [flysystem bundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupFlysystemBundle) that uses the [flysystem library](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/).

Comment: Thank you Matías. I do not have much time to change my own strategy.For this reason, now I prefer to use VichUploaderBundle.Be sure to use your suggestion in the next project